# Building Android Project in Eclipse android.support cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-support-library

I am attempting to make a "hello world" android app with a target and compiler version of 7.1.1 and a minimum version of android 8 (2.2). This error is as shown:[screen shot of MainActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsZtl.png) and the console shows:

C:\Users\Peralta\Desktop\Penn Drive\CIS 120\OCaml\FindIt\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.

C:\Users\Peralta\Desktop\Penn Drive\CIS 120\OCaml\FindIt\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.

C:\Users\Peralta\Desktop\Penn Drive\CIS 120\OCaml\FindIt\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.

Comment: extend AppCompatActivity instead of ActionBarActivity.

Comment: just a note, it's strongly recommended to use AndroidStudio for development AFAIK eclipse plugin is no more supported by google.

Comment: @mdg5435 AppCompatActivity also cannot be resolved to a type

Answer (score 1):

Go to the tabs at the top and select ( Windows -> Android SDK Manager ). Under the 'extras' section, check 'Android Support Library' and check it for installation.

Comment: Theres only Android Support Repository which is already installed

Comment: Try updating it to new version

Comment: Once it is installed, 
the AppCompat library can be found at:
android-sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat
You need to reference this AppCompat library in your Android project.

Import the library into Eclipse.

Right click on your Android project.
1)Select properties.
2)Click 'add...' at the bottom to add a library.
3)Select the support library
4)Clean and rebuild your project.